# XAMPP - Apache HTTP Server has stopped working

Tags: php, windows, apache, xampp

I'm using latest [XAMPP Installers and Downloads for Apache Friends](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard and I keep getting `Apache HTTP Server has stopped working` message(

I Google for that issue and found a lot, but none of these solutions works for me( There are no error(s) in `error.log` and/or `php_error_log`.

I do *NOT* have anything bind'ed to same port(s) as Apache, and my website appears to be working (at least in begin, until Apache stops again).

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: httpd.exe
  Application Version:  2.4.18.0
  Application Timestamp:    5667f02e
  Fault Module Name:    StackHash_a2ad
  Fault Module Version: 6.3.9600.18233
  Fault Module Timestamp:   56bb4e1d
  Exception Code:   c0000374
  Exception Offset: PCH_F6_FROM_ntdll+0x0003C7EC
  OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.272.7
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: a2ad
  Additional Information 2: a2ad1e9ca9dbf2621b83327a68a5efd6
  Additional Information 3: 71fb
  Additional Information 4: 71fb413e23b4a6ea2958a571b78c6d42

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=280262

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Please advise.

Comment: Check if your IIS is running. That might cause the issue.

Comment: I did and it's not.

Comment: do you have a firewall on server that might for some reason triggered to blocks for xampp or its ports?

Comment: no firewall, ports are fine, yet apache http server process/service keeps on crashing(

Comment: It might be windows problem, not apache. Are windows logs telling you something?

Comment: other then apache crashed, nothing useful(

Comment: slightly related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442219/httpd-exe-crashes-when-executing-a-php-script-with-mysql-in-it (comments on answer)

Comment: my app consist of magento commerce, and as I stated earlier it works in begin, so php is able to communicate with mysql.

Comment: so...that is the time to blame Windows and XAMPP. Still, you can check the mysql process, as it can fail not initially but after some minutes (as it's a process). @alexus

Comment: Did you try using [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com)?

Comment: I have this same problem with WAMP, anyone made any progress on it?